# MAC Application crash on button click event

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa

Hello friends I faced problem while creating MAC Application I have two view controllers. when I clicks on button which is placed in first view controller app replace view using below code

```
- (IBAction)gotoEmployeeView:(id)sender
{
    delegate = (AppDelegate *)[[NSApplication sharedApplication]delegate];
    secondViewController *employeeVC = [[secondViewController alloc]initWithNibName:@"secondViewController" bundle:nil];
    [[delegate.window.contentView animator] replaceSubview:self.view with:secondVC.view];
    secondVC.view.frame = ((NSView *)delegate.window.contentView).bounds;
}
```

now I have one button and I have set click event for this button on second view. below id button click event

```
- (IBAction)btnClicked:(id)sender
{
    NSLog(@"clicked");
}
```

and when I clicked on it app was crashed. and get below error

```
2013-08-12 14:33:46.989 Employee Register[1954:303] -[__NSCFString btnClicked:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x10213ace0
2013-08-12 14:33:46.991 Employee Register[1954:303] -[__NSCFString btnClicked:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x10213ace0
2013-08-12 14:33:46.994 Employee Register[1954:303] (
0   CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff8d76cf56 __exceptionPreprocess + 198
1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x00007fff80e47d5e objc_exception_throw + 43
2   CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff8d7f91be -[NSObject doesNotRecognizeSelector:] + 190
3   CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff8d759e23 ___forwarding___ + 371
4   CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff8d759c38 _CF_forwarding_prep_0 + 232
5   CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff8d75c70d -[NSObject performSelector:withObject:] + 61
6   AppKit                              0x00007fff8c5208ca -[NSApplication sendAction:to:from:] + 139
7   AppKit                              0x00007fff8c5207fe -[NSControl sendAction:to:] + 88
8   AppKit                              0x00007fff8c520729 -[NSCell _sendActionFrom:] + 137
9   AppKit                              0x00007fff8c51fbec -[NSCell trackMouse:inRect:ofView:untilMouseUp:] + 2014
10  AppKit                              0x00007fff8c59fb74 -[NSButtonCell trackMouse:inRect:ofView:untilMouseUp:] + 489
11  AppKit                              0x00007fff8c51e7f6 -[NSControl mouseDown:] + 786
12  AppKit                              0x00007fff8c4e9c98 -[NSWindow sendEvent:] + 6306
13  AppKit                              0x00007fff8c4833a5 -[NSApplication sendEvent:] + 5593
14  AppKit                              0x00007fff8c419a0e -[NSApplication run] + 555
15  AppKit                              0x00007fff8c695eac NSApplicationMain + 867
16  Employee Register                   0x0000000100001342 main + 34
17  Employee Register                   0x0000000100001314 start + 52
 )
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're sending a btnClicked message to a NSString object. Can you post the code where you call [... bntClicked] ?

The behaviour you are describing can mean either that the viewController implementing the btnClicked method gets deallocated before the action is called or that the action in interface builder is not set correctly.

You should add a log statement in the dealloc method of the viewController implementing the btnClicked and see that it does not get deallocated before the action is called. If you're using ARC make sure that you have a member data pointing to your view controllers so they don't get released.

Also you should delete the ibaction association in interface builder and do it again making sure that you connect the button to the correct view controller.

Answer (score 0):

Your gotoEmployeeView code looks fine to me.
**NOTE** : `replaceSubview:with:` method causes oldView to be released.

Take a look at [sample project](https://www.dropbox.com/s/bsgpqgot2vvbyrp/viewControllers.zip).

Comment: Hello Parag thanks for your answer but still my app crash on button click event

Comment: Check my sample project.

Comment: may be your problem is in xib files.

Comment: when I run your sample project I got Error ** The scheme 'viewControllers' contains no buildables that can be built for the SDKs supported by the run destination My Mac 64–bit. Make sure your targets all specify SDKs that are supported by this version of Xcode.**